# Is code with try-catch-rethrow equivalent to code w/o try-catch?

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch, language-lawyer, throw

Under which circumstances are the following two codes not equivalent?

```
{
  // some code, may throw and/or have side effects
}

try {
  // same code as above
} catch(...) {
  throw;
}
```

---

**edit** Just to clarify, I'm not interested in (i) deviations from above pattern (such as more code in the catch block) nor (ii) intended to invite patronising comments about the proper usage of `try`-`catch` blocks.

I'm looking for a qualified answer referring to the C++ standard. This question was prompted by a comment by [Cheers and hth. - Alf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/464581/cheers-and-hth-alf) to [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33688702/1023390), stating w/o further explanation that above codes are *not equivalent*.

---

**edit** they are indeed different. stack un-winding will be done in the latter, but not necessarily in the former, depending on whether an exception handler (some `catch` block higher up the stack) is found at run time.

Comment: *Are* there circumstances where they aren't equivalent?

Comment: @user2079303 that's exactly my question.

Comment: Oh, I see. I only read the question which asks when are they not equivalent, which implied that such cases exist. I'd like to know what @Cheersandhth.-Alf is referring to.

Comment: @user2079303 So did I.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The latter mandates stack unwinding, whereas in the former it is implementation-defined if the stack is unwound.

Relevant standards quotes (all from N3337):

> `[except.ctor]/1:` As control passes from a throw-expression to a handler, destructors are invoked for all automatic objects
>   constructed since the try block was entered. The automatic objects are destroyed in the reverse order of the
>   completion of their construction.
>
> `[except.ctor]/3:` The process of calling destructors for automatic objects constructed on the path from a try block to a
>   throw-expression is called “stack unwinding.” [...]
>
> `[except.terminate]/2:` [When the exception handling mechanism cannot find a handler for a throw exception], `std::terminate()` is called (18.8.3). In the situation where no matching handler is found,
>   it is implementation-defined whether or not the stack is unwound before `std::terminate()` is called. [...]

As such, if you want to guarantee that your automatic objects have their destructors run in the case of an unhandled exception (e.g. some persistent storage must be mutated on destruction) then `try {/*code*/} catch (...) {throw;}` will do that, but `{/*code*/}` will not.

Comment: But how can the compiler determine whether an exception handler will ever be found, say from a calling function??

Comment: @Walter I tested this across translation units using clang and the `{/*code*}` did not call the destructor but the rethrow version did. I don't know enough about exception implementations to say how it's done though.

Comment: @Walter: It is not the compiler but the run-time system that determines whether an exception handler can be found. Since destructors called during stack unwinding cannot alter the handler (if any) that will be activated, the system is free (I think this is the meaning of `[except.terminate]/2`) to unwind and destruct while searching for a handler. But alternatively it might first complete the search, and only start unwinding once a handler is found. In the latter case no destruction at all will take place in the case where no handler is found.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen thanks, that's very interesting. The problem with relying on `terminate()` is that the error message may get lost (or is there any guarantee otherwise). That's why I put all code inside `main()` in one outermost `try-catch` block (catching `std::exception`), reporting any messages (`exception::what()`). However, some compilers do implement code that reports that even from `terminate().`

Comment: @Walter: The fact that the stack is not unwound in the absence of `catch` may be due to that the fact that the unwinding actions are linked to from the handler. In the popular (and near ubiquitous) Zero Cost exception model, all the exception handling/stack unwinding code is stashed aside by the compiler in separate code/data (which is how the Zero Cost in case of no exception is achieved), and thus to know which destructors to execute the run-time might very well need the appropriate entries there.

Comment: The concrete rationale for going straight to terminate() if nothing is going to catch the exception ("[two-phase unwind](https://monoinfinito.wordpress.com/2013/03/26/c-exceptions-under-the-hood-8-two-phase-handling/)" in compiler jargon) is that a debugger breakpoint on `std::terminate` will see the stack at the point of the original `throw`.

Answer (score 7):

Elaboratring on [Cheers and hth. - Alf's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33688686/will-throwing-an-exception-in-a-catch-block-lead-to-two-exceptions-being-in-flig/33688702#comment55151171_33688702):

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate :

> std::terminate() is called by the C++ runtime when exception handling
>   fails for any of the following reasons:
>
> 1) an exception is thrown and not caught (**it is implementation-defined
>   whether any stack unwinding is done in this case**)

So stack unwinding might not happen if your

```
{
  // some code, may throw and/or have side effects
}
```

is not within another `try/catch` block.

Example:

```
struct A {
    A() {}
    ~A() { std::cout << "~A()" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
//    try {
        A a;
        throw 1;
//    } catch(...) {
//        throw;
//    }
}
```

[Under coliru's gcc 5.2.0 with -O2](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/da8acc17d00d3747) does not print `~A()`, while with `try/catch` does print.

**UPD**: regarding your edit about separate compilation units, just tested with my local gcc 4.8.2, the behavior is the same: no stack unwinding if there is no `catch`. The particular example:

`a.h`:

```
struct A {
   A();
   ~A();
};

void foo();
```

`a.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A {
   A() {}
   ~A() { cout << "~A()" << endl; }
};

void foo() {
    A a;
    throw 1;
}
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#include "a.h"

int main () {
   //try {
    foo();
   //} catch(...) {
   //  throw;
   //}
}
```

I think that whether there is a `catch` is determined at run time, because anyway when exception is thrown at runtime, the program needs to look for `catch`. So it make sense to choose whether to unwind the stack at runtime too.

Comment: Ah, so it's different in the case where the exception is not caught at all. Can you also elaborate on a how the stack unwinding is useful when the program is going to terminate anyway?

Comment: @user2079303, obviously to do any cleanup code. Just a quick example: you have a remote server that can accept only one connection at time. You will have some `Connection` object in your program, and its destructor will close the connection so that the server will be ready to accept a new connection.

Comment: @user2079303, or even simpler: close a file output stream so that all data that is buffered actually hits the disk.

Answer (score 3):

Semantically that is equivalent. I am not sure, if some compilers might be unable to optimize the unnevessary `try`-`catch` away. I'd prefer to leave the `try`-`catch` block out. That usually makes the code easier to unterstand.

Comment: Can you support your claim (that the codes are equivalent) with a quote form the standard?

Comment: @Walter please note, that I wrote, that it is "semantically equivalent". AFAIK the standard does not state that explicitly, but it is obvious from the descriptions of how the semantics for exceptions, and exception handling.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the "some code" does not exhibit undefined behaviour (in which case all bets are off, regardless of whether you add a try/catch block or not), there will be no difference in end result.   It is technically implementation defined (i.e. an implementation has to document what it does) whether stack unwinding will occur if an exception is never caught, but there has yet to be a report of any implementation that does NOT unwind the stack in such circumstances.  If stack unwinding occurs, all local variables will pass out of scope, and those with destructors will have destructors invoked.

There may or may not be a measurable difference of performance, associated with the overhead of setup before the "some code" is executed, catching the exception (if any) and rethrowing, and any additional cleanup.    The difference will be compiler dependent and, with old compilers, was potentially significant.   With modern compilers, the difference of overhead - if any - would be somewhat less, since implementation techniques for exceptions and exception handling have improved.

Comment: I'm not sure you answer my question. The compiler cannot be sure whether these codes are within a try-catch block, so how can it avoid stack unwinding???

Comment: @Walter the compiler can generate code to *walk* (not unwind) the call stack to find an exception handler and if it doesn't find one act accordingly.

Comment: @jepio your comment is the closest yet to a satisfying answer (see also my recent edit of the OP). -- could you make it into an answer?

Comment: I answered your question and then you edited your post.  So suggesting I haven't answered your question is misrepresentation.    However, there is also nothing in the standards to stop an implementation (which technically can include a complete toolchain, not just a compiler and library) from examining your complete program and causing `std::terminate()` to be called and stack not unwound in circumstances where it can detect an exception is thrown and never caught.   But, as I said, there are no reported cases of implementations doing that sort of thing.

Comment: @Peter thanks for your answer (I have upvoted it). what you're saying in the comment is essentially what jepio said, which is interesting -- I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

In case you catch the basic Exception they are completely the same. You only benefit from catching and rethrowing an exception, if you do something before throw, like logging. But you shouldn't catch Exception. Only ever catch exceptions you now how to recover from.

Comment: There is no "basic Exception" being caught.  You're probably thinking of a feature of a language other than C++.

Comment: @PalleDue No. In the case that they only *catch the basic Exception* it wouldn't be completely the same. The code in the question catches *all* thrown objects.

Comment: I was answering the question thinking it was C#. Until the edit there was no hint that it was c++. Sorry about that.

Comment: @PalleDue The *hint* is in the tags.

Answer (score -1):

Some meaningful clean up can be performed in catch block before rethrow if resources not managed as RAII idiom

```
       {
          // some code, may throw and/or have side effects
        }

        try {
          // same code as above
        } catch(...) {
//Some meaningful clean up can be performed here if resources not managed as RAII idiom
          throw;
        }
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @Walter I just tried to point out a circumstance where these 2 code construct vary potentially

Comment: @Walter ok. Got your point! Will get back if found the answer.